# How could I exclude from the database all string values that non-ASCII characters or in a locale other than English (postgresql)

Tags: postgresql

The database (postgresql) contains characters other than **utf-8**, for example, **Turkish**.

We need to leave the characters only in the English version, with UTF-8 encoding.

**Update**.

- example

ğıüçb(turkish)
çşəöğd (azerbaijan)
یبقفغاتن (Persian)
קורני(Hebrew)

We need to find all the strings that are not English or American (to delete theirs), (leave only the English or American version) because the login must be in English only.

What would a script that scans the entire database look like, and for a certain field (for example, the **login** field contains characters not in **utf-8** encoding or in a locale other than English), specify (will show) the type of client encoding (that is, the one in which the client entered data from his OS).?

Comment: Utf-8 can encode all unicode characters - English, French, Turkish, Mandarin, snowmen. Can you give an example of the actual bytes that are causing a problem and show the encoding setting if the database just to check?

Comment: this seems like an x-y problem  iconv can be combined with diff to find the non-utf8 rows in a pg_dump file.

Comment: I updated above.

Comment: If anything you want to find ***non-ASCII*** characters. “Non-UTF-8” makes no sense here.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
insert into client (username,country) values ('صیdf2بdfdلت', 'per'); 

insert into client (username, country) values ('ㄷㅅdfㅅㅅ89ㅎㅎ', 'korean'); 
insert into client (username, country) values ('ğĞGÇç24ööFc', 'azerb'); 
insert into client(username, country) values ('DhËFGjJopq', 'albany');
```

```sql
select * from client c where (c.username ~* '(?:[a-zA-Z]\d)|(?:\d[a-zA-Z])') is false;
```

**'[[:alnum:]]'** - this expression in this case will not find the necessary strings

```sql
/*
This expression searches for all strings that are not in the Unicode range:
48 - 57 - digits
65 - 90 - uppercase letters
97 - 122 - lowercase letters

~*    case-insensitive matches

^  $  set at the beginning and at the end, indicate the exact definition of the condition

+    quantifier, indicates that there can be any number of characters that a string has.
*/

select * from login l where (l.username ~* '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$') is false;
```